# How to create a git diff/diff-tree/archive between 2 commits with versions of files at exactly this point (not head)

Tags: git, diff, archive

If I want to compare and export 2 commits in the past against each other, I can do a git diff to list all modified files, so far so good. 
But if I want to archive those files at exactly the version of the files at the last commit, how can I achieve that? 
Let's say a file got deleted after the last commit, git archive will fail, because the file listed by git diff could not be found anymore. Do I have to checkout the latest of the commits which I'd like to compare or is there any elegant solution?

`git archive --output=test.zip HEAD $(git diff --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB  --name-only SHA1 SHA2)` 
fails for files which still existed in the diff but not in head anymore

Comment: "But if I want to archive those files at exactly the version of the files at the last commit of the two" ... then just archive the last commit. If the file was deleted, it won't be in the archive. A commit is *not* a changeset, it's a full snapshot. (That's why you can diff the two snapshots to see what changed.)

Comment: Yes, I know it's no changeset, but if my git working directory contains the head revision and I'd only like to archive the delta between 2 commits (ie. the changeset) it fails for files which are missing from my working directory. Furthermore, git archives the current version of a modified file, not the version which matches the changeset.

Comment: An archive is also a snapshot. If you extract an archive into an empty directory, you obtain the snapshot. If you extract an archive into a non-empty directory, you get ... well, what you deserve. :-) Neither tar nor zip archives can contain any sort of "remove" directive. As for the archive produced by `git archive`, note that `git archive` takes an optional `<tree-ish>`. You're supplying `HEAD`, but you should supply the identifier of the second commit.

Comment: Why not just `git checkout SHA2` before doing the operation? If you have unsaved work, stash it or put it in a dev branch first, then checkout sha2 and run git archive.

Comment: Sure, but git diff may show file paths which existed in the "changeset" but not in head anymore, so git archive won't "find" them anymore physically and thus fails

Comment: @joanis that's exactly what I'm asking. is this the only way to return to those versions?

Comment: Just did a quick test: `git archive SHA2 -- $(git diff ...` should do what you want. When you typed `git archive HEAD ...`, you explicitly asked Git to look at HEAD instead of SHA2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the commit you want the archive to save files from explicitly:

```
git archive --output=test.zip SHA2 -- $(git diff --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB --name-only SHA1 SHA2)
```